# Progressive scrolling with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a database witch contains 1000 products. I have a list which displays 10 products at one time. This grid is scrollable. I want to load products 10 by 10.
What is the best way to do this with angularjs ? I am looking for a method which need shortest code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called pagination and if you want to achieve this in less amount of time then you must go for any already available module.

I have used [Infinite Scroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) It is very easy to use and would help you to implement things in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for lib called "infinite scroll". You can find this app here https://github.com/ifwe/infinite-scroll

Where in the controller you put this code:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['tagged.directives.infiniteScroll']);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.fetching = false;

  // Fetch more items
  $scope.getMore = function() {
    $scope.page++;
    $scope.fetching = true;
    $http.get('/my/endpoint', { page : $scope.page }).then(function(items) {
      $scope.fetching = false;
      // Append the items to the list
      $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
    });
  };
}]);
```

And this is your view:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul tagged-infinite-scroll="getMore()">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{ item.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once it detect you scroll is at the end of the `ng-repeat` items it calls `getMore` function to load new items. Remember to add to the endpoint limit, and offset to load rest of the data, not same data every time.

Comment: Is there a way to animate this ? Is it possible to use jquery for animation ?